# A word for "look down on"

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a friend who is a teacher but she looks down on her job. She finds it of little value. Is there a single word to describe her feelings for her occupation?

Comment: This question is beginning to produce really poor-quality answers, and it doesn't really follow the criteria for single-word requests. Improving the question along the lines of the help referenced in the banner should counter the problem with both the poor-quality answers and help the community converge on a suitable expression.

Comment: On what basis do you call them "poor-quality answers? What sort of "context" would you expect the questioner to provide, beyond what was given?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock The answers you can't see (with less than 10k rep) were low-quality. The help is in [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could say she is dismissive of her job.

**Dismissive**:
Feeling or showing that something is unworthy of consideration.

Answer (score 4):

I have three verbs that describe your friend's feeling or attitude:

**disparage**: (vt) regard or represent as being of little worth.

*Disparage is most commonly used to refer to how someone speaks or writes of something, but it does include the thought or feeling as well.*

**undervalue**: (vt) rate (something) insufficiently highly; fail to appreciate.

*Included in the use of this word is the belief that the thing someone undervalues does indeed have value.*

**vilipend**: (vt) regard as worthless or of little value; despise.

*Not as common as the other two, but apt, and somewhat sinister.*

If you are looking for an adjective, then you might try:

**disdainful**: (adj) showing contempt or lack of respect.

Or there's also:

**contemptuous**: (adj) showing contempt; scornful.

Comment: Disdain is, of course, both a noun and a verb ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's a feeling of **underestimation**.
She underestimates the value of her profession.
She takes her profession for granted.

underestimate -   To consider (someone) to be less capable or effective than is actually the case. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/underestimate)

Comment: The  question doesn't say whether the teacher's understanding of the value of her profession is wrong, ie does not provide any evidence to support your answer.

Comment: @jwpat7 Sorry, it's the best I could come up with.

Answer (score -1):

**Beneath**. You could say, teaching is beneath her. I didn't like saying that BTW :( 
A Formal definition:

> considered of lower status or worth than. "she's in love with a man
>   who is rather beneath her" synonyms:  inferior to, not so important as,
>   lower in status than, lower than, below;

Comment: Why the downvote?